# How to render Unicode text in SFML?

Tags: sfml

I am using SFML in Windows10 (64bit).
SFML version is 2.5.1.
SFML libs using `GCC 5.1.0 TDM (SJLJ) - Code::Blocks - 32-bit`
`gcc` version is `gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)`

I want to render Japanese text with `sf::Text`.
But below code is not working.
This code showing square characters (like a □□□□）

How to render Unicode (Japanese) text in SFML?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(void) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "Sample");

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("res/fonts/sans.ttf");

    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString(L"日本語");
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your font file _contain_ those characters?

Comment: Yes. Font support Japanese.

Comment: I change font then success to display text. But the before font support Japanese. Is it the compatibility of the font?